# Column editing and renaming of a tab-delimited table in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Apologies for the basic question, but I am pretty stuck. I have a basic tab-delimited text file called `map.txt`. The first line of the file is column names, preceded with the `#` character. Note, this is a tab-delimited file. Here is the output of `head map.txt`:

```
#SampleID   BarcodeSequence LinkerPrimerSequence    sample_type Description geneticSampleID
OSBS.087.39.M.32.18.20140227    TCCCTTGTCTCC    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A1   OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.41.M.37.33.20140227    ACGAGACTGATT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A2   OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.23.M.15.31.20140227    GCTGTACGGATT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A3   OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
OSBS.047.21.M.20.3.20140227 ATCACCAGGTGT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A4   OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
OSBS.119.23.M.18.38.20140227    TGGTCAACGATA    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A5   OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
OSBS.047.41.M.22.36.20140227    ATCGCACAGTAA    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A6   OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
OSBS.087.41.M.40.21.20140227    GTCGTGTAGCCT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A7   OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.21.M.5.11.20140227 AGCGGAGGTTAG    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A8   OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
OSBS.119.39.M.27.5.20140227 ATCCTTTGGTTC    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A9   OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
```

I would like to change the names `geneticSampleID` to `Name` and `BarcodeSequence` to `Index1`. I would then like to delete all columns except for the newly named `Name` and `Index1` columns. I'd like the first line of the file to remain the colum names `Name` and `Index1`, preceded by the `#` character. Changing the names of the columns is straightforward enough in vim, deleting columns is not.

Desired output:

```
#Index1 Name 
TCCCTTGTCTCC OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
ACGAGACTGATT OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
GCTGTACGGATT OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
ATCACCAGGTGT OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
TGGTCAACGATA OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
ATCGCACAGTAA OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
GTCGTGTAGCCT OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
AGCGGAGGTTAG OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
ATCCTTTGGTTC OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with shell commands like `awk` and `sed`, for example:

```
cat map.txt | awk '{ print $2, $7}' | sed 's/BarcodeSequence/#Index1 Name/'
```

Output:

```
#Index1 Name 
TCCCTTGTCTCC OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
ACGAGACTGATT OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
GCTGTACGGATT OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
ATCACCAGGTGT OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
TGGTCAACGATA OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
ATCGCACAGTAA OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
GTCGTGTAGCCT OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
AGCGGAGGTTAG OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
ATCCTTTGGTTC OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
```

Although now we are using `sed` to replace 1 column name with 2 new names and that feels hacky to me. So in this case I would prefer the awk-only way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "#Name", "Index1"} NR>1 { print $2, $7}' map.txt
```

Comment: Adding an action `NR==1 {$2="Index1"; $6="Name"}` to the `awk` script gets rid of the need for `sed`.

Comment: This is super close. There is one complication. The Codes `1A1` etc. are part of the `Description` field. The full entry is `Plate 1A1`. This is probably complicated because of the space. The desired output would be `OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen` where currently `1A1` is.

Comment: @chepner of course you are right. Personally I think this code is cleaner. But that is a matter of taste of course.

Comment: @rje changing 6 to 7 gets the right columns printed, but I no longer have the column name `Index1`. Only `name`.

Comment: @rje awesome. Last question. Any way to have the first line be preceded by the `#` character? If not I can always do this in vim.

Comment: @colin yup, 1 moment.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -f2,6 inputfile | sed '1{ s/geneticSampleID/Name/; s/BarcodeSequence/Index1/; s/^/#/; }'
```

1. Cut just filters columns 2 and 6
2. Sed substituted geneticSampleId to Name `s/.../.../` and BarcodeSeuqnce to Index, but only for the first line `1{ .. }`
3. Also sed adds predceding # character `s/^/#/`
4. One day I will learn awk!

Live version available at [onlinegdb](http://tpcg.io/fXc6yc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `awk` like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; print "Index1", "Name"} NR>1{print $2, $6}' file
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/OY3VES)

**Output:**

```
Index1  Name
TCCCTTGTCTCC    OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
ACGAGACTGATT    OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
GCTGTACGGATT    OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
ATCACCAGGTGT    OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
TGGTCAACGATA    OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
ATCGCACAGTAA    OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
GTCGTGTAGCCT    OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
AGCGGAGGTTAG    OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
ATCCTTTGGTTC    OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
```

Comment: there seems to be a missing `'` somewhere. I keep getting an error saying this is not closed.

Comment: This is working fine on my shell, are you sure there is no copy/paste error.

Comment: no longer a close error, but the output prints only ythe names, and not the index. If I change `$6` to `$7` I get the `index1` field, but the `name` field is blank, and it is not preceded by the `#` character.

Comment: In the "working demo" The wrong entries are in the `Name` field. The first entry should be `OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen`.

Comment: indeed, there is a space between `Plate 1` and `1A1`,however the fields are tab-delimited, not space delimited.

Comment: Works great! I accepted a different answer only because it was done first, but I appreciate this!

Comment: You may select any answer of your choice but using `$7` is hugely error prone because in fact it is 6th column that you want. What if you have `Plate 1A1 abc` in 5th column. Correct solution is setting `FS` and `OFS` to tab character.